# pig set data type of all columns

Tags: apache-pig, udf

Im wondering if there is a way to set the data type of an arbitrary number of items in a tuple. For example if I create a field using $(1..) and I know that all the items will be integers, can I set that? something like:

```
.... GENERATE (chararray)$0 (int..)($1..)
```

I'm passing this tuple to a UDF and want to save time in parsing and converting DataByteArray to Int.